# "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied" error while minification and bundling of CSS in ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, amazon-web-services, bundling-and-minification

I recently transferred my ASP.NET web forms application from a managed VPS to AWS EC2 using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. When I was using my web app in managed VPS, the bundling and minification was working correctly. But after the transfer to Amazon server, the javascript is bundled and minified successfully but not CSS. When I opened minified CSS file in browser's View Source, it showed following page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally, after some research on Google I figured out what was actually going wrong. With the help of the solution given here http://forums.asp.net/post/5012037.aspx, I came to know that the virtual path of the bundle must not match with any physical path in your web application's folder. So, I was calling bundle like this `<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/css" />` and my web app's physical root path also contains a `css` sub-folder inside `Content` folder. So, I renamed my bundle to `styles` and then used it like `<webopt:BundleReference runat="server" Path="~/Content/styles" />`. Now, it's working fine.